# UIKit is initial view controller does not work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I recently updated to xCode 13 on my M1 macbook.

I am following this apple tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/creating-a-storyboard-app

But I have an issue. I remove the old view controller and create a new Table View Controller, then I checked the is Initial View Controller checkbox, I run the app but it only shows a white background.
[image]

I tried to run the app without checking the checbox, but it only shows a black screen.
[image]

Comment: I did not change the code at all, I only make what that step of the tutorial shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see nothing because the table is empty. (In iOS 15, an empty table is truly empty.)

You have put a table view controller in your storyboard, but there also needs to be some code. In particular, there needs to be a UITableViewController subclass with some code to populate the table — and (most important) the table view controller in the storyboard needs to have *its* class set to be *that* UITableViewController subclass.

But you have not (yet) performed those steps.